# Access to Mirror API if Glass was given to me by a friend or possible partnership

Tags: google-mirror-api

A friend of mine was selected to be an explorer for Google Glass and he gave me the glasses as he is not planning to do any development but I am. Is there any way for me to get access to the API now that I own a pair of the glasses? Or is anyone out there with Mirror API access maybe willing to partner with me in exchange for access to their API account as my friend uses his Google account for personal use and I don't want to ask him for access to his personal information.

Comment: It is not... You may not commercially resell any Device, but you may give the Device as a gift, unless otherwise set forth in the Device Specific Addendum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collaborating with a member of the Glass Explorer Program [is allowed](https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3064131), but only the explorer is granted access to the APIs Console switch to toggle the Mirror API. However, they can share this access with you in much the way they can loan you their Glass.

They can do this by creating an APIs Console project and adding you as a [team member](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#DifferentRoles). Have them follow these steps:

1. Create an APIs Console project
2. Enable the Google Mirror API: [image: enable mirror api]
3. Navigate to the teams panel
4. Add your account as a team member. [image: add member to team]

You then be able to access the client ID and secret for this project that has the Mirror API enabled.

Comment: Excellent answer. Everyone is envious of my Glass and now I can let them collaborate!